# Laravel insert database with loop inside

Tags: laravel, sql-insert, laravel-blade

I have an array called type.
In my db i have 4 columns called `type_1` `type_2` `type_3` `type_4`

I am trying with the help of a loop put this at once

Also, I have another problem that is pushing the array to my blade this I will describe in the end!

With no loop it works 
Example

```php
$r            = new PR;
$r->type_1    = $type[1];
$r->type_2    = $type[2];   

$r->save();
```

What i have try was:

```php
$r = new PR;

foreach ($type as $key => $value) {
    $r->type_.$key = $value;
}

$r->save();
```

Also i have try this loop on blade  calling {{$r->type_$i}} but doesn't work

Comment: You should instead have a relation between types and `PR`s.

Comment: check your key is start with 0 or 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not valid PHP syntax: `$r->type_.$key = $value;`

If you want to access properties of an object by strings, you should use the key as a string between `{` and `}`. For example:

```
foreach ($type as $key => $value) {
    $r->{"type_$key"} = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loop that has poor performance, you can try using `saveMany` method on eloquent model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models